# Is there a limit on the size or number of conditions in Webform 7.4.12?

Tags: webforms

I have been using Webform with Conditions for a year or more and the Conditions work fine on small forms.  Indeed I have several other small working forms using conditionals live on the site at the moment and these work as designed and expected both for Administrator and Authenticated Users alike.

But in the case of a much larger Form (essentially a similar Form with more of the same as the ones that work), it works fine in development for the Administrator, but few or none of the Conditionals work for Authenticated Users.

In desperation:

- deleted all the Data in the Form AND
- the Field definitions in the Webform AND
- all the Conditionals AND
- then re-created them all afresh.

This took 4-5 hours again without any success.

I now seem to have exhausted my testing regime on the Form setup itself trying to resolve the problem.

This is weird because the form works correctly for Administrator but not Authenticated Users, so this leads me to believe that there is a limit somewhere in the Webform code that limits the extent of a large number of Conditionals for Authenticated Users, but not Administrators?  Because it is not a basic permissions setup issue, because it works correctly with small forms.

Can anybody throw any light on this please?

Comment: Is this something to do with the PHP setup on the Server?